Sheet formula for finding total score for cell with same name multiply by bias and array
Attached sheet need a formula to array, divide and multiply. Please also include a formula that will auto include more rows when data is added.
Array and multiply



Name
Dance x 3
Jump x 2




Ali
4
8


Val
2
6


Ali
6
8


Val
8
4




Eg.
Ali Dance = ((4+6)/2)x3 = 15
Ali Jump = ((8+8)/2)x2 = 16

Result I want.



Name
Count
Dance x 3
Jump x 2




Ali
2
15
16


Val
2
15
10




Thanks Z.. for the edit, i am puzzled what went wrong the table look ok in the previe.

this has been a known issue for years. Not sure when they will fix it.

One way to do this:
=ARRAYFORMULA( 
   MAP(AC4:AU4,LAMBDA(c,
     MAP(TOCOL(Z5:Z,1),LAMBDA(r,
       AVERAGE(FILTER(FILTER(D5:V,C5:C=r),D4:V4=c))))))
   *AC3:AU3)


